# How can I read from a computed field? In Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, computed-field

I have a computed field in a model called **page_price**.

```py
Class Page(models.Model):
    page_price = fields.Float(compute='compute_page_price')

    def compute_page_price(self):
        self.page_price = 7  # this value is an example
```

If I show this field in a view, it shows 7.

The problem is when I try to get the value from another model.

```py
Class Book(models.Model):
  book_price = fields.Float(compute='compute_book_price')

  def compute_book_price(self):
    # page_id has the value of a Page row id
    page_price = self.env['Page'].search([('id', '=', page_id)])[0].page_price
    self.book_price = page_price * 10
```

Here, the value of book_price is always 0 instead of 70.
The vaule of page_price inside the compute_book_price function is 0 instead of 7.
Why is that and how can I obtain the correct value?

**Note:** If the **page_price** field is defined as a Float field instead of a computed field, the result of book_price is 70.

Comment: self.book_price = float(page_price) * 10 or try to print the value of page_price in function compute_book_price(self): and check what its return

Comment: Actually Compute function should be called above the fields declaration

Comment: @VigneshwaranThenraj , in the new API you can call the compute function after the fields declaration: http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#computed-fields
 I have print the page_price value inside compute_book_price and it is 0

Comment: I have also same problem, Did you get any solution `Mou Tio` ???

Comment: @TahirNoor I am afraid I have no solution yet.

Comment: Please have a look at it. it may help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50035832/how-to-get-computed-field-value-in-search-orm-in-odoo`