# How to get computed field value in search orm in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I have defined a `computed field` with compute method in `odoo 10` and now i want to get its value in `search orm` but its value remain False, and when I tried `store=True` its value not being changed. 
if anyone has solution please let me know, I'll highly thankful.
My code is:

```
balance_amount = fields.Float(string="Balance Amount", compute='_compute_loan_amount')

@api.one
def _compute_loan_amount(self):
    total_paid = 0.0
    for loan in self:
        for line in loan.loan_lines:
            if line.paid:
                total_paid += line.amount
        balance_amount = loan.loan_amount - total_paid
        self.total_amount = loan.loan_amount
        self.balance_amount = balance_amount
        self.total_paid_amount = total_paid
```

when i use `search_count`below:

```
loan_count = self.env['hr.loan'].search_count([('employee_id', '=', values['employee_id']), ('state', '=', 'approve'),
                                                   ('balance_amount', '!=', 0)])
```

it always get count value even `balance_amount` equals to `Zero`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things you have to do here.

1. Define recomputation dependencies and either use `@api.multi` and a for loop over `self` or use `api.one` and skip a for loop. If i understand your compute methode correct:

```py
@api.multi
@api.depends('loan_lines.paid', 'loan_lines.amount', 'loan_amount')
def _compute_loan_amount(self):
    for loan in self:
        total_paid = 0.0
        for line in loan.loan_lines:
            if line.paid:
                total_paid += line.amount
        balance_amount = loan.loan_amount - total_paid
        loan.total_amount = loan.loan_amount  # ???
        loan.balance_amount = balance_amount
        loan.total_paid_amount = total_paid
```

2. Try to use a float rounding with e.g. 2 decimals, because floats can produce values like 0.000000000000000002 and that would break your search.
3. You either have to store the value or have to define a `search` method. Second approach is more difficult (in my experience).

Comment: Thanks `CZoellner`